# Правильно ли говорить "сходи ко мне"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Правильно ли говорить **сходи ко мне** (речь идет о странице в соцсети)?
Либо все же нужно сказать "зайди ко мне" или "иди ко мне"?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **зайди на мою страницу, зайди ко мне.**

Глагол ***сходить*** для виртуальных перемещений не предназначен:

**СХОДИТЬ**, св. 1.  **Пойти куда-л. и, побыв там, вернуться обратно.** С. в гости. С. в магазин. С. за хлебом. С. к соседям.

Он подразумевает **обязательное возвращение**, а это ненужная информация.

Глагол ***зайти*** предполагает **побывать где-то с определенной целью**: зайти на мою страницу, чтобы посмотреть что-то новое.

**ЗАЙТИ**, св. 1. Идя по пути, побывать где-л., посетить кого-, что-л., наведаться к кому-л., куда-л. (**обычно с какой-л. целью**). З. к приятелю,

Answer (score 2):

"*Сходи ко мне*" - выражение, неудачное почти в любом контексте (кроме случая, когда "ко мне" условно значит "в мой в дом" - что-нибудь взять без меня и т. п.): "сходить" выражает пожелание, чтобы собеседник переместился *в направлении удаления* от говорящего или от места общей беседы, *приблизившись* при этом к названному месту (здесь: ко мне = к собеседнику). В результате возникает логическое **противоречие между удалением и приближением** (по отношению к собеседнику). Что касается стиля, то на интернет-страницу "**заходят**" (условно перенесясь в пространстве) или просто "**заглядывают**" (в традиционном смысле - как на страницу книги) - с "ко мне" и то, и другое сочетается.